# Magento 2 - Checkout custom step URL not loading page

Tags: magento2, checkout

I've created a custom step in magento 2 checkout before shipping address step.
Firstly, its not getting selected on page load.
Secondly, after selecting that step checkout url changes to http://www.magento2.com/checkout/#isLogedCheck

On pressing F5 its giving all steps but no step is getting selected

Following is the code for js

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator',
    'Magento_Customer/js/model/customer',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
],
function (
    $,
    ko,
    Component,
    _,
    stepNavigator,
    customer,
    quote
) {
    'use strict';
    /**
    * check-login - is the name of the component's .html template
    */
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Custom_Checkout/check-login'
        },

        //add here your logic to display step,
        isVisible: ko.observable(false),
        isLoggedIn: customer.isLoggedIn(),
        //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
        stepCode: 'isLogedCheck',
        //step title value
        stepTitle: 'Logging Information',
        logoutUrl: quote.getLogoutUrl(),
        customerEmail: quote.getCustomerEmail(),

        /**
        *
        * @returns {*}
        */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();
            // register your step
            stepNavigator.registerStep(
                this.stepCode,
                //step alias
                null,
                this.stepTitle,
                //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                this.isVisible,

                _.bind(this.navigate, this),

                /**
                * sort order value
                * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                */
                5
            );

            return this;
        },

        /**
        * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
        * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
        * for switching to your custom step
        */
        navigate: function () {

        },

        /**
        * @returns void
        */
        navigateToNextStep: function () {
            var loginFormSelector = 'form[data-role=email-with-possible-login]',
            emailValidationResult = customer.isLoggedIn();
            if (!customer.isLoggedIn()) {
                $(loginFormSelector).validation();
                emailValidationResult = Boolean($(loginFormSelector + ' input[name=username]').valid());
            }
            if (!emailValidationResult) {
                return false;
            }

            stepNavigator.next();
        },
        navigateToMe: function () {
            stepNavigator.navigateTo('isLogedCheck');
        }
    });
});
```

Following is the code for HTML

```
<li class="card">
<div class="card-header" role="tab" id="headingOne" data-bind="click: navigateToMe">
  <h5 class="mb-0">
    <a data-bind="i18n: 'Login Information'" data-role="title" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkoutSteps" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
    </a>
  </h5>
</div>
<div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible, attr: { id: stepCode }">
  <div class="card-block">
   <!--<div class="step-title" data-bind="i18n: stepTitle" data-role="title"></div>-->
    <div id="checkout-step-title"
         class="step-content"
         data-role="content">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->
            <div data-bind="if: !isLoggedIn" class="block social-login-authentication-channel account-social-login">
                <div class="block-content">
                                    <div class="actions-toolbar social-btn social-btn-actions-toolbar facebook-login">
                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook">
                                <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
                                Sign in with Facebook                    </a>
                        </div>
                                    <div class="actions-toolbar social-btn social-btn-actions-toolbar google-login">
                            <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google">
                                <span class="fa fa-google"></span>
                                Sign in with Google                    </a>
                        </div>
                            </div>
            </div>
            <div data-bind='if: isLoggedIn'>
                You're already logged in as <span data-bind="text: customerEmail"></span>. Not you ? <a data-bind="i18n: 'Log Out', attr: { href: logoutUrl,title: $t('Log Out') }"></a>
            </div>
        <form class="navigate-to-next-step" data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Continue'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Kindly suggest what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might have something to do with: `isVisible: ko.observable(false),`

This will mark the step as `_complete`, so nothing you want to do in that step will be executed.

Also, I don't think you're supposed to `return this;` in the `initialize`-method.